# Cannot create unknown type error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception

> Exception: Cannot create unknown type error
>   "'{http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation}RadDatePicker'"

```
    public static object Visualize(string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            var xdoc = new XDocument(XElement.Parse(new StreamReader(filepath).ReadToEnd()));
            Code = xdoc.ToString();
            XmlReader xmlReader = xdoc.CreateReader();
            return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader); //<-- thrown here
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message,"Visualize error", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Exception occurs during runtime when I call the above method with a xaml file that contains this component. If I call this same file, but the part where components are declared is missing, it works fine.

How do I fix it?

Comment: show us how you declared the component! how do you expect us to guess what's wrong if not?

Comment: xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"

And references to the dlls

Comment: Also, the first [google result](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Exception%3A+Cannot+create+unknown+type+error&oq=Exception%3A+Cannot+create+unknown+type+error&aqs=chrome.0.57j58&sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is explaining the cause and the solution

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'm not using System.Xaml.XamlReader; I use System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader

Answer (score 0):

The issue may come from your own XAML code which expects a resource not existing on your XAML. If you have a merged resource on your App.xaml, don't expect that it will be seen by XAML control. I ran into the same issue which I had to explicitly define that merged resource again on my control XAML view.

My issue is below, kind of misleading to the actual cause.

`Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation}RadGridView'`